# Higher order derivative of a ratio

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives

Can we compute 
\begin{align}
\frac{d^k}{dx^k} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} \Big|_{x=0}
\end{align}

where  $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ satisfy

1. $ g(x)\neq 0$
2. $\frac{d^k}{dx^k} f(x) \Big|_{x=0}=0$  and $\frac{d^k}{dx^k} g(x) \Big|_{x=0}=0$  for $k$ odd.

Comment: The quotient rule could work, but a general formula would be rather cumbersome. Instead, you could write $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=f(x)(g(x))^{-1}$ and use the [general Leibniz rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Leibniz_rule) to write a formula for the $k$th order derivative.

Comment: @user170231 I see. Do we have the property that if $ \frac{d^n}{dx^n} g(x)=0$ then  $ \frac{d^n}{dx^n} \frac{1}{g(x)}=0$

Comment: @Boby  Certainly not.  Consider $g(x) =x$ for a counterexample when $n \ge 2$.

Comment: @Glitch   Since, this is so. I don't think Leibnitz rule is much use if want to use my condition.s